# 特定の時間になればタイマーが起動するアプリを作成したが、指定の時刻になってもカウントダウンが動作しない

Tags: java, android

Javaを用いてAndroidアプリを開発しています。特定の時間になればタイマーが起動するように、localtimeとisafterを用いて条件分岐を設定しましたが、指定の時刻になってもカウントダウンが動作しません。どうすればいいでしょうか？

```
package com.example.countdowntimer;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public void compareDate1() throws ParseException {

        LocalDateTime date1 = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-02-7T10:48:00.000");
        LocalDateTime date3 = LocalDateTime.now();

        if (date1.isAfter(date3)) {
            CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(3600000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    int time = (int) millisUntilFinished / 1000;
                    int time2 = (int) millisUntilFinished / 60000;
                    int time3 = (int) millisUntilFinished / 3600000;
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv)).setText("" + time3 + ":" + time2 + ":" + time % 60);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv)).setText("終了");
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

compareDate1がどこからも呼ばれていません。
Activityのライフサイクルのどこかに組み込むのを意図されているのでは？